# How do I view my app logs in Azure spring boot apps?

Tags: azure-spring-boot

I am using **Azure Spring Apps**, and I am deploying a very simple Spring App

I have deployed my spring app to azure like so :

```
az spring app deploy --resource-group myResourceGroup --service myService --name myName --artifact-path target/myApp-0.1.0.jar
```

On the azure portal it says that the deployment has "failed"

[image]

I would like to view my app logs to see what went wrong, as everything works fine for me locally.

Is there a straightforward simple way to view my spring boot logs in azure?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure CLI to get logs:

> az spring app log tail -n xxx -s xxx -g xxx --subscription xxx --lines 200

Refs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/spring-cloud/app/log?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: This does not work for me : No instances found for deployment 'default' in app 'shape-shop-app'. Do I need to setup a default instance?